# Have trouble doing push to a sub-array in a 2D JS array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Suppose I made a 5 by 2 matrix populated by integer 9
`let arr = Array(5).fill(Array(2).fill(9));`

Now I want to push integer 8 into the fourth line of the matrix by doing
`arr[3].push(8);`

I ended up getting `[[9,9,8],[9,9,8],[9,9,8],[9,9,8],[9,9,8]]`. All lines in the matrix have been pushed 8.
Why?

I found out if I did things like below, I got what I wanted, but why?

```
arr[3] = [...arr[3]];
arr[3].push(8);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**: This is because all 5 arrays are sharing a reference to the exact same array
i.e. `Array(2).fill(9)` => [9,9]

**Quick Solution**: Use `Array.form` to create a `deep-copy` for each layer

```javascript
let arr = Array.from({length: 5}, e => Array(2).fill(9));
```

or try any other solution from these answers ([ref 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949813/array-fillarray-creates-copies-by-references-not-by-value), [ref 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578478/array-prototype-fill-with-object-passes-reference-and-not-new-instance), [ref 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613126/unexpected-behavior-using-array-map-on-an-array-initialized-with-array-fill))

See the working solution below (notice the shallow copy in the console)

```js
// PROBLEM

// Shallow-copies
let arr1 = Array(5).fill([...Array(2).fill(9)]);
arr1[3].push(8);

// writing to the document
document.write('Shallow -> ', arr1)
// loggin in console
console.log('shallow ',  arr1)


// SOLUTION

// deep-copies
let arr2 = Array.from({length: 5}, e => Array(2).fill(9));
arr2[3].push(8);

// writing to the document
document.write('<br><br> Deep -> ', arr2)
// loggin in console
console.log('deep', arr2)
```

---

**Details**: As mentioned in the documentation here (5th point in Description [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#description)) about the first parameter of `.fill` which is the array you are passing in i.e. `[9,9]`

> If the first parameter is an object, each slot in the array will reference that object.

Exact scenario is mentioned inside the documentation as well, see this code snippet [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#using_fill)

This shows that all the items are basically a reference to the same object [also known as `shallow copy`], altering one item will result in the same changes in every other item.

`Array.from` fixed this issue as `Array(2).fill(9)` will now create a new array on every element of the array. Learn more about `Array.from` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

---

This fix you mentioned at the end is working because by using spread operator `[...arr[3]]` we are creating a deep copy of this [9,9] array on the 4th index, which is not a reference to that same initial array [9,9] anymore so, now changing this item at 4th index will only change the 4th item's array itself.

Note This spread operator `...arr` is only creating a `single level` `deep copy` so, if (supposedly) this `arr[3]` contains another multi-level array inside it, then only the first level will be created as a deep copy and all the inner ones will remain as shallow copies [i.e. same reference to the object]